# C and C++ difference in sizeof('x')

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars)

Why when using C does `sizeof('x')` return 4 but `sizeof('x')` in C++ returns 1?

C++ normally strives to be nothing more than a superset of C so why do the two results diverge?

**Edit**
Just some further clarification. This seems like a deliberate move on the part of the standards committee and I assume changing the size of 'x' would not have been done without a good reason. I am interested in what the reason is.

Comment: More or less a duplicate of [Different sizeof results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046/different-sizeof-results), [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/) and [Understanding sizeof(char) in 32 bit C compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451266/) and perhaps one or two others. Found with http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+[c%2B%2B]+sizeof+character+literal.

Comment: none of the duplicates explain why.

Comment: @deus: It's just a design decision. The "c" way means the compiler has to make fewer decisions about type promotion ('cause "promotion" happens every time) which may have played a roll: the machines of the early seventies were slow and had limited memory, so simple compilers were a must.

Comment: See the answers from Malx and Johannes Schaub in [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/).

Comment: "C++ normally strives to be nothing more than a superset of C" Where did you read that? Completely false. C++, in the beginning, had to be close to C so programmers could try to adopt it. But it's certainly wrong to say they *strive* to make it a superset. They're different languages, that's it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To quote the C++ standard ISO 14882:2003, annex C.1.1 clause 2.13.2

> **Change**: Type of character literal is changed from int to char
>
> **Rationale**: This is needed for improved overloaded function argument type matching. For example:
>
> ```
> int function( int i );
> int function( char c );
> function( ’x’ );
> ```
>
> It is preferable that this call match the second version of function rather than the first

(annex C describes the incompatibilities between C and C++)

Comment: More or less what I thought but nice to see in black and white.

Comment: Of course, they *could* have just introduced a "`char` literal" syntax - eg `C'x'` is of type `char`, in the same way that `L'x'` is of type `wchar_t`.

Comment: Note, a multicharacter literal eg `'abcd'` *is* still of type `int`, with implementation-defined value.

Answer (score 7):

C++ is not a superset of C. Particularly if you use the "current" versions - a compiler in C++0x mode will choke on C99 code.

Comment: But that is because the (then) new C99 standard was not incorporated into C++

Comment: @deus-ex C99 was out for years before C++0x started. If they wanted to make C a subset, they would have included the changes. In fact, they did include some of them. `#include <cstdint>` refers to C99's `stdint.h`.

Comment: C and C++ have been diverging slightly with recent versions of standards. I wouldn't expect C99 to be rolled into C++0x or vice versa, with respect to the common feature sets.

Answer (score 5):

Because is C, 'x' is actually an int, while in C++ it's a char.

C++ tries is tighten up strong typing that was a bit lax in C.

Comment: Intriguing behavior... I'm not much of a C guy but this surprises me. So when you call `printf("%c", 'x');`, 4 bytes are pushed onto the stack for the varargs, but in C++ it would only be 1 byte? How could that work, considering the CRT doesn't know what language is calling it?

Comment: @tenfour, nope - 4 bytes are pushed in C++ too.  varargs calls have lots of type promotion rules.

Comment: @tenfour: In C++ variadic argument always go through integral promotions, meaning that `char` and `short` types are always promoted to `[unsigned] int` before being passed to a variadic function. The same thing happens in C.

Comment: learn something every day :) Now I wonder why a char literal is an `int` in C?

Comment: @tenfour, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars