# Different answers from strlen and sizeof for Pointer & Array based init of String

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C: differences between pointer and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array)
>   [Different sizeof results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046/different-sizeof-results)

Basically, I did this...

```
 char *str1 = "Sanjeev";
 char str2[] = "Sanjeev";
 printf("%d %d\n",strlen(str1),sizeof(str1));    
 printf("%d %d\n",strlen(str2),sizeof(str2));
```

and my output was

```
7 4
7 8
```

I'm not able to give reasons as to why the `sizeof str1` is 4. Please explain the difference between these.

Comment: @Eugen Constantin Dinca:  It's not a dupe because this question is about the sizeof operator and how it works.

Comment: If I run the code, I get the same output on each line - `7 8 / 7 8`; it is a 64-bit machine, of course.  This would probably have misled you about what is going on!

Comment: @Robert: this question targets a subset of what's covered in the other question's answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because sizeof gives you the size in bytes of the data type.  The data type of str1 is char* which 4 bytes.  In contrast, [strlen](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strlen.3.html) gives you the length of the string in chars not including the null terminator, thus 7.  The sizeof str2 is char array of 8 bytes, which is the number of chars including the null terminator.

See this entry from the C-FAQ: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/krnotes/sx9d.html

Try this:

```
 char str2[8];
 strncpy(str2, "Sanjeev", 7);
 char *str1 = str2;
 printf("%d %d\n",strlen(str1),sizeof(str1));    
 printf("%d %d\n",strlen(str2),sizeof(str2));
```

Comment: `%d` is wrong format specifier to print result of `sizeof`. `sizeof` returns `size_t` which should be displayed using `%zu` specifier introduced by C99 standard

Answer (score 6):

`str1` is a pointer to char and size of a pointer variable on your system is 4.
`str2` is a array of char on stack, which stores 8 characters, "s","a","n","j","e","e","v","\0" so its size is 8

Important to note that size of pointer to various data type will be same, because they are pointing to different data types but they occupy only size of pointer on that system.

Comment: It is important to add that the size of a pointer is 4 because the author's machine is 32bit, for 64bit machines a pointer is always of size 8. This is the number of bytes needed to represent a memory address in a 32 or 64bit architecture

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(str1) is sizeof(char*)`
whereas `sizeof str2 is sizeof(char array)`

sizeof(char array) should be equal to strlen(char array) + 1 (NULL termination).
Well if you pass the char array to a function, its size as shown by sizeof will change. The reason is char array is passed as char* only.

Answer (score 1):

```
 char *str1 = "Sanjeev";
 printf("%d %d\n",strlen(str1),sizeof(str1));
```

`strlen()` gives the length of the string which is `7`. `sizeof()` is a compile time operator and `sizeof(str1)` gives the size of pointer on your implementation (i.e `4`).

```
char str2[] = "Sanjeev";  
printf("%d %d\n",strlen(str2),sizeof(str2));
```

`sizeof(str2)` gives the size of the array which is `8*sizeof(char)` i.e. `8` [including the `NUL` terminator]