# difference between sizeof and strlen in c

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different answers from strlen and sizeof for Pointer & Array based init of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925927/different-answers-from-strlen-and-sizeof-for-pointer-array-based-init-of-strin)

Can anybody help me in understanding difference between **sizeof** method and **strlen** method in c programming?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`strlen()` is used to get the length of a string stored in an array.

`sizeof()` is used to get the actual size of any type of data in bytes.

Besides, `sizeof()` is a compile-time expression giving you the size of a type or a variable's type. It doesn't care about the value of the variable.

strlen() is a function that takes a pointer to a character, and walks the memory from this character on, looking for a null character. It counts the number of characters before it finds the null character. In other words, it gives you the length of a C-style null-terminated string.

The two are quite different. In C++, you do not need either very much, strlen() is for C-style strings, which should be replaced by C++-style `std::strings`, whereas the primary application for `sizeof()` in C is as an argument to functions like `malloc()`, `memcpy()` or `memset()`, all of which you shouldn't use in C++ (use new, `std::copy()`, and `std::fill()` or `constructors`).

Comment: +1, but even using `std::copy` and `std::fill` you have to provide the number of elements of the array if you are using C-style arrays. The point is not much `memcpy`/`memset` vs STL algorithms, but C-arrays/strings vs `std::vector`/`std::array`/`std::string`/other containers.

Comment: "sizeof is a compile-time expression" - except when used on a VLA in C99.

Comment: Just a nit, but... there's a `NULL` pointer and a "null pointer", but it's a nul character (or what I prefer: a `'\0'` character).

Comment: @James: saying "NULL character" or "null character" for `0` is about as valid as saying "BELL character" or "bell character" for `7`, or "line feed", "(horizontal) tab" etc. I also prefer "nul" just to help distinguish type and context, and using the ASCII-endorsed names of ASCII characters provides a kind of consistency. But let's not pretend that's anything other than a three-letter contraction of "null" :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop It is something more: it's the official name of the character in the original ASCII standard (which seems to have a decided preference for three letter names).  In a C++ context, I prefer `'\0'`, because that's the way you write it in code.  You could also write just `0`, but then it's not clear that you're dealing with a character.  The C++ standard does call it a "null character type value charT()".  But in C++, `NULL` is a macro, defined by the standard, so I'd avoid that (unless you mean the macro).

Comment: sizeof is an operator, so you don't need parenthesis around the argument, unless it's a type name. `sizeof x` and `sizeof(x)` both work, but you must write `sizeof (int)`.

Comment: we must  remember that the sizeof()  is to get the actual size of any type of data in bytes(Any type of data)

Answer (score 13):

`sizeof` is not a *method*. It is a compile-time construct that determines the amount of memory a particular type or a variable occupies. `strlen`, on the other hand, is a *function* that counts the number of consecutive non-zero `char` values starting at the specified location in memory (which happens to be the same as determining the length of a zero-terminated C string).