# For any string "char name[10]="test"",is strlen(name)+1 always guaranteed to be same as sizeof(name)?

Tags: c, sizeof, strlen, size-t

For a string `name[]`,can we use `strlen(name)+1` and `sizeof(name)` **interchangeably** in our code without second thought?Aren't they same?I checked about it and found out even the return type for both is same,`size_t`.And after all `sizeof` calculates the size as a multiple of bytes and a character occupies one byte, while `strlen()` calculates the number of characters excluding the `\0` due to which we have to add a 1 to equate it to the result of `sizeof`.

So unless the size of the character is something other than 1 byte,aren't the two interchangeable and same for all practical purposes?Like while allocating dynamic memory for example....

Comment: pls look at this --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590332/difference-between-sizeof-and-strlen-in-c

Comment: @Bill Doesn't answer what I am asking, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which book are you reading? `sizeof` is an operator that tells you how many bytes a type (or in your case, the type of an object) occupies. `strlen` is a function that tells you where the first `'\0'` character is located, which indicates the end of the string.

```
char foo[32] = "hello";
printf("sizeof foo: %zu\n", sizeof foo);
printf("strlen(foo): %zu\n", strlen(foo));
```

`sizeof foo` is 32 regardless of what you store in `foo`, but as you can see `strlen(foo)` is in fact `5`, where you would expect the `'\0'` (NUL-terminator) to go.

In terms of dynamic allocation, you can expect to store the return value of `malloc` in a pointer.

```
char *foo = malloc(32);
strcpy(foo, "hello");
printf("sizeof foo: %zu\n", sizeof foo);
printf("sizeof (char *): %zu\n", sizeof (char *));
printf("strlen(foo): %zu\n", strlen(foo));
```

In this case, `sizeof foo` is `sizeof (char *)`, because it gives you the number of bytes in a `char *` (pointer to char). This is very different to the `strlen` function because the size of a pointer to char is constant during runtime.

`sizeof (char)` is *always* 1. That's required by the C standard. If you find an implementation where that isn't the case, then it isn't a C implementation.

Perhaps your book might explain this, which is why I asked... but there are plenty of poor quality books. Please do answer that question!

Comment: Damn!! It never occurred to me that `sizeof` will always give the whole size and `strlen()` will give only the characters stored,even though it's a fraction of the total size.

Comment: As of `sizeof` being an operator, I knew that :-) !!

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture No. Not "characters stored". Read the answer again. `strlen` returns the length of the string, which is the offset of the first `'\0'`. If you copy "\0hello" into the array, instead, then `strlen(foo)` will return 0.

Comment: @Abhineet `NULL` is not `NUL`; One is a pointer, the other is a character. Please don't edit my answers until you understand the syntax of the `sizeof` operator correctly.

Answer (score 4):

For a declared array like `char name[10]`, `sizeof(name)` is the size of the entire array, regardless of what data is stored in it.  `strlen(name)` returns the number of characters in the array before the first `0`.  Behavior of `strlen` is undefined if there aren't any zeros in the array.