# C program - sizeof string with \0 characters

Tags: c, string, sizeof

Explain how sizeof determines the length of the string.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "Sasindar\0Baby\0";
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What results does it give, and what do you expect?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because easily Googleable and almost certainly duped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between sizeof and strlen in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590332/difference-between-sizeof-and-strlen-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof` does not determine the length of the string. It determines how many bytes a structure takes in memory.

In your case, the structure is `str`, an array of bytes. The compiler knows how many bytes, including the two trailing `'\0'`s, was placed into the array, so it produces the proper size at compile time. `sizeof` has no idea that `str` is a null-terminated C string, so it produces 15.

This is in contrast to `strlen`, which interprets your string as a C string, and returns the count of characters before the first `'\0'`.