# C language sizeof, strlen and strncpy for chinese words

Tags: c

I haven't long time in touch with C language. I have some questions related to chinese words and strncpy.

```
char* testString = "你好嗎?"
sizeof(testString) => it prints out 4.
strlen(testString) => it prints out 10.
```

When i want to copy to another char array, i have some issue.

char msgArray[7]; /* This is just an example. Due to some limitation, we have limited the buffer size. */

If i want to copy the data, i need to check

```
if (sizeof(testString) < sizeof(msgArray)) {
    strncopy(msgArray, testString, sizeof(msgArray));
}
```

It will have problem. The result is it will only copy a partial data.

Actually it should have compared with

```
if (strlen(testString) < sizeof(msgArray)) {

}
else {
   printf("too long");
}
```

But i don't understand why it happened.

If i want to define to limit the characters count (including unicode (eg. chinese characters), how can i achieve to define the array? I think i can't use the char[] array.

Thanks a lot for all the responses.

My workaround solution: I finally decide to cut the strings to meet the limited bytes.

Comment: These are unicode strings, you need to use wcslen, etc. sizeof is not doing what you think, it's the size of a pointer.

Comment: `testString` is a pointer. The size of a pointer is not relevant for copying strings. You need to find the length of the array it might point to.

Comment: @simonzack: `wcslen` is for `wchar_t` array, not `char` array. And when it comes to `strcpy`, the underlying encoding does not matter. It is byte-per-byte copy.

Comment: @SiyuanRen Yes but what he has is essentially a `wchar_t` array.

Comment: @simonzack: No, it is not a `wchar_t` array. Depends on his compiler, it may be encoded in either utf-8 or gbk. One must use `L"你好嗎?"` to declare a `wchar_t` array literal.

Comment: @SiyuanRen True, good point.

Comment: `strncpy` is a terrible function at the best of times, it should be avoided

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8590332/694576

Comment: the code needs to `#include <wchar.h>  then set the 'locale' to the proper value, then use the wide char functions, like `wsclen()` which will return the length (in wide characters) of a wide char array

Answer (score 5):

Pointers are not arrays. `testString` is a pointer and therefore, `sizeof(testString)` will give the size of pointer instead of the string it points to.

`strlen` works differently and only for null terminated `char` arrays and string literals. It gives the length of the string preceding the null character.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of `char* testString = "你好嗎?"` depends on the compiler. One option would be to investigate what your compiler is doing by outputting individual characters via `%d` .  It might be generating a UTF-8 literal.

In the C11 standard you may write one of the following:

```
char const *testString = u8"你好嗎?";   // UTF-8 encoding
```

or

```
wchar_t const *testString = u"你好嗎?"; // UTF-16 or UCS-4 encoding
```

With these strings, there is no way in Standard C to work with *Unicode characters*. You can only work with code points and/or C characters.  `strlen` or `wcslen` respectively will give the number of C characters in the string but this might not correspond to how many glyphs are displayed.

---

If your compiler does not comply with the latest standard (i.e. it gives errors for the above lines) then to write portable code you will need to only use ASCII in your sourcefile.

To embed unicode in string literals you could use `'\xNN'` with UTF-8 hex codes.

---

In both cases your best bet is probably to use a third-party Unicode library such as ICU.

---

For the second part of the question, I'll assume you are using UTF-8.  The result of `strlen(testString) + 1` is the number of characters you need to copy. You say you are stuck with a fixed-size 7-byte buffer. If that is true then the code could be:

```
char buf[7];

if ( strlen(testString) > 6 )
    exit(1);   // or jump to some other error handling

strcpy(buf, testString);
```

The `strncpy` should be avoided because it does not null-terminate its buffer in some circumstances; you can always replace it with `strcpy` or `snprintf`.

Answer (score 1):

normally you can use wchar_t to represent UTF characters (non-English characters), and each character may need 2 or 4 bytes. And if you really want to count number of characters in a quick way, use uint32_t(unsigned int) instead of char/wchar_t because UTF32 is guarantee each character (including non-English character) will have the same size of 4 bytes.

sizeof(testString) will only give you the size of a pointer itself which is 4 in 32bit system and 8 in 64bit system.

use wcslen to get the string len if you're using wchar_t; if you're using uint32_t, you need to write your own strlen function similar as follow:

```
size_t strlenU32(const uint32_t *s) {
    const uint32_t *u = s;
    while (*u) u++;
    return u - s;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not pro, but you may try somthing like this:

```
char* testString = "你好嗎?\0"; //null-terminating char at the end
int arr_len = 0;
while(testString[arr_len])
arr_len++;
```

As result, it returns 10, whih is number of array field, so if you multiply it by the size of single byte, you will get actual length of the string.

Regards, 
Paweł

Comment: There is no need of adding `'\0'` there . That's is already a string literal