# Under what conditions is it safe to use std::memcpy to copy between objects?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, memcpy, object-layout

Under what set of conditions is it safe to use `std::memcpy` to copy from one object to another?

For example, what conditions must `T`, `src` and `dest` satisfy for the following to be safe:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void copy_bytewise(T& dest, const T& src) {
  std::memcpy(&dest, &src, sizeof(T));
}
```

The only thing we can assume about `src` and `dest` is that they don't overlap<sup>1</sup>. In particular either of `src` or `dest` may be a reference to a member or base class.

I am interested in answers which refer to the standard, but if this diverges from common practice (e.g., the de-facto C++ ABI from Itanium) I'd also like to know.

Note that `T` satisfying the [*TriviallyCopyable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) (TC) concept is not sufficient, as [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/jBeRwD) shows. `base` is TC yet not memcpy-safe (due to re-use of padding for members of a derived class).

I am especially interested if there is *any* condition on `T` alone that is sufficient (and not necessarily necessary), without requiring conditions on `src` and `dest` (that cannot, in general, be statically determined).

---

<sup>1</sup> Specifically, my assumption is that if they *do* overlap, they are still safe to copy under the same conditions on `T` as for `std::memcpy`, but using `std::memmove` instead. If assumption is incorrect, it could be part of an answer.

Comment: This is a followup to [discussion in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463341/how-to-use-memset-in-c/56464048?noredirect=1#comment105828377_56464048).  https://godbolt.org/z/jBeRwD example showing that being an Aggregate seems to matter (public vs. private members).  Other clues include https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#POD mention of when that ABI decides to put derived objects in the padding of the base class or not based on when anything that could break that being UB in all versions of the ISO C++ standard.

Comment: Isn't the point of `memcpy` that it doesn't have requirements on the types?  It is the only way in C++ to safely perform type-punning.

Comment: @HenriMenke, eh no. Using `memcpy` has fairly strict requirements on the types involved, or else it will do damage. Consider any type a user-defined copy constructor: obviously just copying the bytes over is unlikely to do what the copy constructor would have done.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Well, of course, but that is also not what `memcpy` is supposed to do.  It literally copies memory.

Comment: @HenriMenke - I think this "language lawyer" question is not for you, it requires a lot of background knowledge on UB, memcpy, the various type concepts in C++, etc. It's hard to even answer your questions/comments without assuming a lot of existing background.  I recommend background reading of the linked and related questions.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: How would you get two pointers/references to two objects of the same type to overlap?

Comment: @NicolBolas - I guess the most obvious, and possibly only, example would be if they are the same object (i.e., "overlap" but not "proper overlap"). In that case, it is my understanding that `std::memcpy` is not allowed regardless of anything else.

Answer (score 5):

From [[basic.types]/3:](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#3)

> For any trivially copyable type `T`, if two pointers to `T` point to distinct `T` objects `obj1` and `obj2`, where neither `obj1` nor `obj2` is a base-class subobject, if the underlying bytes ([intro.memory]) making up `obj1` are copied into `obj2`, `obj2` shall subsequently hold the same value as `obj1`.

In short:

> what conditions must T satisfy for the following to be safe

`T` must be trivially copyable; that's the only condition that `T` must satisfy. The other requirement is not a restriction on `T`, but a restriction on the nature of the objects potentially being copied. Which means it's not something you can statically determine.

Comment: Thanks. So, in practice, for the `copy_bytewise` function I wrote, there is _no_ trait, existing or contemplated, that would make that safe for any `T`, because of the base class issue? I should be clear that I was asking about restrictions of on instances of (sub)objects of type `T`, although I didn't do a good job of writing it, and it affected a bit the language you used in your answer. I am making a small (in characters) edit to clarify and you may want to update your answer.

Comment: I have changed the language "conditions on `T`" to "conditions on `T`, `src` and `dest`" which I think is clearer. LMK if you think the change is too big. I think your answer still completely applies, but just some of the language could be updated.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Don't forget: "point to ***distinct*** `T` objects"

Comment: Is there a stronger condition on `T` that removes the need for additional (dynamic) conditions on `src` and `dest` objects? In practice, there seems to be (e.g., gcc overwrites padding sometimes even when the `dest` object isn't known), but I don't know if this is covered by the standard or if there is a trait for it.

Comment: If you think that deserves a separate question, LMK - I don't want to diverge too far from the original text since that would be unfair to your existing answer.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Well, you could require that `T` is declared `final` and thus cannot be a base class subobject. But that's about it.

Comment: Thanks. Makes [this trait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_final) unexpectedly useful.