# C - how to add to the end of a char array after realloc()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, realloc

I have a short char array called "array". I'm trying to realloc more space to it then add more chars onto the end. for some reason when I print the array, these extra characters don't show up, although they do display when I index them individually.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char *array = malloc(2);
    array[0] = 'b';
    array[1] = '\0';
    char stringToAdd[] = "honey";
    array = realloc(array, (16));
    int pos;
//add stringToAdd into array one char at a time
    for (pos = 0; pos < 5; pos++){
        array[2+pos] = stringToAdd[pos];
        printf("%d ", 2+pos);
        printf("%c ", array[2+pos]);
        printf("%s\n", array);
    }
    array[pos] = '\0';
    int k = sizeof(array);
//should print out the string "bhoney" and its length
    printf("%s, length = %d\n", array,k);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
2 h b
3 o b
4 n b
5 e b
6 y b
b, length = 8
```

also the length of the array seems to be 8 no matter how much space I try to realloc to it?

Comment: OT: regarding `char *array = malloc(2);`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "malloc failed" );`  to output to `stderr` your error message "malloc failed" and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  This is not recoverable, so the next statement should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `array = realloc(array, (16));`  along with my comment about `malloc()` there is the consideration:  The function `realloc()` can fail.  When it fails, then a NULL pointer value will overlay the original pointer in `array()`  The result is a unrecoverable memory leak.  Suggest: `char temp = realloc(array, (16));  if( ! temp ) { // handle error and exit }   array = temp;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added the characters after the null terminator. Printing a string stops at the null.

Assign the new characters to `array[1+pos]` instead of `array[2+pos]`. This also goes for adding the new null terminator after the loop, it should be

```
array[1+pos] = '\0';
```

You could also use `strcat()` instead of the loop:

```
strcat(array, stringToAdd);
```

It will find the null terminator automatically so you don't have to know the offset, and add the new null terminator properly.

`sizeof(array)` is the size of the pointer (8 bytes), not the length of the string. If you want the string length, you should use `strlen(array)`. See [difference between sizeof and strlen in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590332/difference-between-sizeof-and-strlen-in-c)

Comment: wouldn't `strcpy` be better given we already know where the end of the string is?

Comment: My point in suggesting strcat is so that we don't have to keep track of the offset, just let it find it automatically.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear since you mentioned it as an alternative to looping, which `strcpy` is more of a drop-in replacement for.  Or perhaps `strncpy` given the loop as-written is set to stop after 5 iterations.

Comment: Yeah, I added more clarification. The loop is written to stop after 5 iterations because that's how long `honey` is. I don't think he intended this to be any different from the string length, he just hard-coded the length.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
for (pos = 0; pos < 5; pos++){
    array[1+pos] = stringToAdd[pos];
    printf("%d ", 1+pos);
    printf("%c ", array[1+pos]);
    printf("%s\n", array);
}
array[1+pos] = '\0';
```