# How to decrypt using a passphrase and salt using the crypto++ lib?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I'm trying to `decrypt` a string that has been encrypted using `openssl`, `evp_aes_128_cbc`, and a `password/salt`

I have succeeded `decrypting` it using `openssl`, but not using the [crypto++](https://cryptopp.com/) lib.

The `key` generated on the `crypto++` matches the `openssl` `key` but the `iv's` doesnt.

The code result in an exception in the line `stf.MessageEnd();`

its breaks in the `crypto++` file `filter.cpp` at:

```cpp
            if (length != s)
                throw InvalidCiphertext("StreamTransformationFilter: ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size");
```

where length is `24` and `s` is `16`...

---

`c++/openssl` encryption function:

```cpp
    #include <openssl/rand.h>
    #include <openssl/evp.h>
    #include <openssl/bio.h>

     std::string stringToBase64(const std::string& input) 
     {
        BIO* bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    
        BIO* base64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
        BIO_set_flags(base64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);  // No line breaks
    
        BIO* bio_chain = BIO_push(base64, bio);    
        BIO_write(bio_chain, input.c_str(), input.length());
        BIO_flush(bio_chain);
    
        char* encoded_data;
        long encoded_length = BIO_get_mem_data(bio, &encoded_data);
    
        std::string base64_string(encoded_data, static_cast<size_t>(encoded_length));
    
        // Free the BIOs
        BIO_free_all(bio_chain);    
        return base64_string;
    }

   
    std::string encrypt(std::string str, const char* password, const char* salt)
    {
        unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH];

    unsigned char derived[32]; // 32 bytes for both key and IV

    if(!PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(password), strlen(password), 
      reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(salt), strlen(salt), 
      1000, EVP_sha1(), 32, derived)) // Derive 32 bytes
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        return std::string();
    }

    unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];

    // Use the first 16 bytes as the key
    memcpy(key, derived, 16);
    // Use the remaining 16 bytes as the IV
    memcpy(iv, derived + 16, 16);

    if (EVP_CipherInit(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), key, iv, true) != 1) 
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        return std::string();
    }
        
        const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = str.size();
        int len = 0;
        int outLen;
        
        int blocksize = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(ctx);
        std::string cipherBuf;
        cipherBuf.resize(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE + blocksize);
            
        if (EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx, reinterpret_cast<uchar *>(cipherBuf.data()), &outLen, reinterpret_cast<uchar *>(str.data()), str.size()) != 1)
        {
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
            return std::string();
        }        
        len += outLen;
      
        if (EVP_CipherFinal(ctx, reinterpret_cast<uchar *> (cipherBuf.data() + len), &outLen) != 1)
        {
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
            return std::string();     
        }        
        len += outLen;
         
        cipherBuf.resize(len);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx); // Cleanup
    
        str = stringToBase64(cipherBuf); 
        memset(cipherBuf.data(), 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE + blocksize); // Clear cipherBuf    
        return str;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        const char* password = "password123";
        const char* salt = "salt123";

        std::string enc = ecrypt("test123", password, salt);

        size_t saltLen = strlen(salt);
        std::string derived_key(16 + saltLen, '\0'); // AES-128

        CryptoPP::PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA1> pbkdf;
        pbkdf.DeriveKey(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&derived_key[0]), derived_key.size(), 0,
                        reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(password), 
                        strLen(password), 
                        reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(salt), 
                        saltLen, 1000); // '1000' same as on the openssl function
        
        CryptoPP::SecByteBlock key(16), iv(saltLen);
        std::memcpy(key.data(), derived_key.data(), key.size());
        std::memcpy(iv.data(), derived_key.data() + saltLen, iv.size());
        
        CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder;
        std::string key_hex, iv_hex;

        encoder.Attach(new CryptoPP::StringSink(key_hex));
        encoder.Put(key.data(), key.size());
        encoder.MessageEnd();

        encoder.Attach(new CryptoPP::StringSink(iv_hex));
        encoder.Put(iv.data(), iv.size());
        encoder.MessageEnd();

        std::cout << "Key: " << key_hex;
        std::cout << "IV: " << iv_hex;

        
        CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, key.size());
        CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption(aesDecryption, iv);
      
        std::string dec;
        CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stf(cbcDecryption,  new CryptoPP::StringSink(dec));
        stf.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(enc.data()), enc.size());
        stf.MessageEnd();
    }
```

Comment: Post the full OpenSSL code regarding the encryption so that a repro is possible, or at least complete, (non-productive) test data: Plaintext, password, salt and ciphertext.

Comment: Note that `EVP_BytesToKey()` is not `PBKDF2/HMAC`, i.e. you are using different key derivation functions.

Comment: See [here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/OPENSSL_EVP_BytesToKey) for Crypto++.

Comment: @Topaco i see, do you know how i could modify the openssl function to HKDF

Comment: The Crypto++ code does not apply HKDF, but PBKDF2/HMAC. Do you mean this? If you want to use PBKDF2/HMAC in the OpenSSL code (which is much more secure than `EVP_BytesToKey()` BTW), see [`PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC.html).

Comment: Also take care when determining the lengths of key and salt in the Crypto++ code, see [`sizeof()` vs `strlen()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590332/difference-between-sizeof-and-strlen-in-c).

Comment: @Topaco i have changed `EVP_BytesToKey` to `PBKDF2` now the 'keys' match but the `iv` dont, is there something wrong in the use of the `saltLen`?

Comment: I don't see an IV anywhere in your OpenSSL code. You seem to derive 64 bytes (`EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH`), which you use completely as key, and to apply the salt as IV for encryption (more precisely in `EVP_CipherInit()`), which is both wrong. You have to derive 32 bytes with the KDF, the first 16 are the key (corresponding to `EVP_aes_128_cbc()`), the following 16 the IV.

Comment: @Topaco derive using only the password?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The KDF uses various input parameters: Password, salt, digest, iteration count and length of the byte sequence to be generated. You have to generate 32 bytes and use the first 16 bytes as key and the second 16 bytes as IV. With this key and IV you then perform the decryption/encryption.

Comment: @Topaco i did, the ivs still missmatch

Comment: Your ongoing overwrites of the old code make troubleshooting difficult. Instead of overwriting the code all the time, you should append changes to the question. This line `std::string derived_key(16 + saltLen, '\0')` (from Rev. 4) in the Crypto++ code generates a byte sequence of wrong length (namely 16+7=23 for `salt123` as salt). You have to generate 32 bytes: `derived_key(32, '\0')` (as up to Rev. 3). Apart from that, I can't reproduce the issue with the code (from Rev. 6): On my machine, both codes generate the same key and IV.

Comment: @Topaco could you share your code? im in doubt about this part: https://pastebin.com/99yN5En3

Comment: The linked code returns the same 32 bytes sequence as my code for identical input data. To make it identical to the code posted in the question (Rev. 6) the iterations count (8th parameter in `pbkdf.DeriveKey()`) must be changed from 1 to 1000.