# I can't understand an error in a function

Tags: c

This function make a strange error after using it several times and I really can't understand the reason behind it.

```
    char *get_range(char *str,int min,int max){
    char *_res=(char *)malloc(sizeof(str));
    int cur=0;
    while (min<max){
        _res[cur]=str[min];
        min++;
        cur++;
        }
    return _res;
    }
```

The problem is that after using this function several times, the output comes with additional chars and I don't understand why.

Notice: The additional chars are allway used returned by the function beffor

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(str));` reserves enough memory for a string of 7 characters at most. You probably should change this to `malloc(strlen(str)+1);`.

Comment: 1) `sizeof(str)` is pointer (`char *`) size. 2) `_res` doesn't null-terminated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046/different-sizeof-results

Comment: @squeamishossifrage although correct its very misleading. you dont say why 7. (or 3). I know why but I had to think about it a bit.

Comment: It sounds like you want to return a substring. See [this](https://ideone.com/xkOapz), it may help.

Answer (score 2):

```
  char *_res=(char *)malloc(sizeof(str));
```

is wrong. `sizeof(str)` is measuring the size of a char pointer. This is either 4 or 8 (typically) depending on your system (32 or 64 bit).

You need

```
char *_res=(char *)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

strlen returns the number of characters in the string, and you need to add 1 for the terminating 0;

Second you have to add a terminating zero at the end, do:

```
_res[cur] = '\0';
```

before returning

Comment: Really thank you ....i have another question
if i am working on a array of strings......I should add the terminating char manually to every string is this true ?!

Comment: every c string must have a '0' at the end, thats the definition of a string in C