# Why does a pointer not inherit the fixed size of a string literal

Tags: c++, c-strings

Is there any hidden feature of the `sizeof` keyword I'm missing here when it's applied to a literal and not a pointer *initialized to another literal*?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char* string = "Hello, World!";

    // sizeof(...) on literal; returns 14 (the actual length)
    std::cout << "sizeof (with literal): " << sizeof("Hello, World!") << std::endl;

    // sizeof(...) on initiated pointer; returns 4 (wonder why?)
    std::cout << "sizeof (with variable): " << sizeof(string) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or is it just my compiler *"optimizing"* the source?

---

The [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046/different-sizeof-results) may seem to answer my question, but only **partially**.

The answer provided makes note on C++ not being able to pass entire arrays as function parameters and as such receiving array arguments as pointers instead

(Which logically, argument pointers could be of any size).

To which I can guess here that the **literal** is probably optimized to be a *fixed-sized array* and the **pointer** has an *arbitrary size* during compile-time, but the question is: **why**?

---

It's easier to wrap my head around this if the variable had been uninitialized: 
`char* string; // Arbitrary size that's mutable (usually 4 bytes)`

but not in this case scenario when its initiated to a fixed-size literal: 
`const char* string = "Hello, World!"; // Fixed-size of 14 allocated to variable?`

After all the valid characters of the variable had been specified in initiation *(which implicitly gives a length by the number of characters initialized)*, would that not make the variable inherit the allocated size of the literal?

Comment: The type of a string literal is `const char[N]` not `const char *`  Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sizeof string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392200/sizeof-string-literal)

Comment: @user4581301 no `std::string`s in the question.

Comment: My apologies. I misread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To which I can guess here that the literal is probably optimized to be a fixed-sized array

A literal is not "optimized" to be a fixed-sized array. A string literal **is** a fixed-sized array: It is not a matter of optimization.

> and the pointer has an arbitrary size during compile-time

It's unclear what you mean by "arbitrary". The size of a data pointer is determined by the target system. On a 64 bit x86 system, the size of a pointer is 8 bytes for example.

> ```
> const char* string = "Hello, World!"; // Fixed-size of 14 allocated to variable?
> ```

What a pointer points to does not affect the size of the pointer.

> would that not make the variable inherit the allocated size of the literal?

Only thing that affects the size of a variable is the type of the variable. If the type of the variable is `const char*`, then size of that variable is exactly same as `sizeof(const char*)`.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is a pointer, and it’s size is the size of a pointer, regardless of what it points at. Initializing a pointer to point at a string literal doesn’t change that — it’s still a pointer.

Don’t conflate arrays and pointers. They are two different things. The name of an array in most contexts decays into a pointer to its first element, and that often confuses beginners. One of the situations where the name of an array does not decay into a pointer is when the name is the argument to the `sizeof` operator. That’s why `sizeof “abcdef”` is 7 and not the size of a pointer.